# Dynamic Handing of Bigquery table schema while inserting data into BQ table from variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, python-bigquery

I am trying to append data to BQ table using python code which requires dynamic schema handling. 
Can anyone provide me the link to handle above scenario.

Comment: Can you share an example of your code and give more details of the issue you are having?

Comment: I want to write a row in a .csv file each time I called the write a file function , which then should update only the new row in BQ table from this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example code of [loading a .csv file into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source) using the python client library:

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# filename = '/path/to/file.csv'
# dataset_id = 'my_dataset'
# table_id = 'my_table'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
job_config.autodetect = True

with open(filename, "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config)

job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

print("Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.".format(job.output_rows, dataset_id, table_id))
```

Also check this part of the documentation to know more about [appending data into tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_using_a_local_file) from a source file using the same or different schema.